# Scipy is not getting instaleed in pypy3

Tags: python, scipy, pypy

I am using `pypy3` in my windows 10. I have already installed `numpy`, but `Scipy` is not getting installed in pypy3.

Below is the console verbiage of error log while installing `Scipy`

```
 Collecting scipy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/5b/5afcd1c46f97b3c2ac3489dbc95d6ca28eacf8e3634e51f495da68d97f0f/scipy-1.3.1.tar.gz (23.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 23.6MB 939kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc5m_lyu1'
         cwd: C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h29rfz4x\scipy
    Complete output (100 lines):
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    system_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\lib-python\3\importlib\_bootstrap.py:206: UserWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 436, got 208
      return f(*args, **kwds)
    setup.py:388: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h29rfz4x\scipy\pip-wheel-metadata'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])))
    Running from scipy source directory.
    C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 197, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 69, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 237, in run_setup
        self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 505, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 501, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-tk6fpn90\overlay\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "setup.py", line 403, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError(msg)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3.6-v7.1.1-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Tuhin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpc5m_lyu1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you just do pip install SciPy ?

Comment: Looks like `scipy` is more dependent on these fast math libraries (blas, atlas).  `numpy` can do without them.

Comment: If `pip` doesn't work, I would recommend using Anaconda instead. In fact, I would suggest using Anaconda for your Python environment management even if `pip` works.

Comment: if scipy is dependent to blas,atlas, what step do i need to take o install them?

Comment: Seems that most Python users use the Anaconda distribution on Windows.  That can handle the details for packages like `scipy`.  BUT, I don't know how that works with pypy3.

Comment: is there any way to install scipy manually?

Answer (score 2):

Just try `pip install Scipy`
sometimes, the simple methods work better. Also, check out the requirements of Scipy on its website https://www.scipy.org/stackspec.html .